# What does min mean?

Tags: genetics, terminology, chromosome

I read that

> "trp operon is located at 27 **min** on E.coli chromosome."

What does "min" mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Min* means minutes. Minutes are counted for interruption points since onset of DNA transfer in F-pili-mediated conjugation. The point "0" is not associated with *ori*, but is close to *thr*. The total chromosome size is 100 min (time taken for conjugation).

See:

- [Linkage Map of Escherichia coli K-12, Edition 10: The Traditional Map](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC98936/)
- [Recalibrated linkage map of Escherichia coli K-12](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC98936/)

Comment: Well.. I am not sure if this 100 minute is for the replication or transfer. I am still confused because [this](http://utminers.utep.edu/rwebb/html/the_e__coli_genome.html) site says it is replication. In fact I did write conjugation first and changed to replication.

Comment: in fact replication is much faster in regular conditions.

Comment: Yes, 100 min is the time required for the transfer, since replication time itself is ca 40 min.